# How to add multiple input boxes with different names

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button to add another input box every time it is clicked but I also want it to add an increasing number the end of the input name. I have this code to add more inputs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addInput()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("inputs");
    x.innerHTML += "<input type=\"file\" name=\"photo\" />";
}
</script>
```

What can I do to make it so that every time a new form is added it will add a higher number to the end of name="photo" so that I can process images with my php script correctly?

default the form is:

```
 <input type="file" name="photo">
```

but I would like to add a number to the end of photo every time a new input is made to have an output like this.

```
 <input type="file" name="photo">
 <input type="file" name="photo2">
 <input type="file" name="photo3">
 <input type="file" name="photo4">
```

etc

Comment: I could give you an answer using jQuery if you like?

Comment: I have it figured out now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` in your form name, then your php script will automatically convert those inputs into an array, that way you don't even have to worry about appending numbers anymore.

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
```

If you want to do it using javascript, easiest way is to have a variable that keeps track of the number of inputs

```
var inputNumber = 0;
function addInput()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("inputs");
    x.innerHTML += "<input type=\"file\" name=\"photo\"" + inputNumber + " />";
    inputNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a count and initialize it to 0, then increase it in every call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=0;
function addInput()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("inputs");
    x.innerHTML += '<input type=\"file\" name=\"photo\"'+count+' />;
    count++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: note: you don't need to escape " if you are wrapping your string around '

Answer (score 1):

andeas's answer is probably best for this specific situation. But in general if you want a counter that will increase every time a function is called, try:

```
(function {
    var counter = 0;
    window.myfunction = function() {
        // do stuff, use counter if needed
        counter++;
    }
})();
```

`counter` can be treated as if it were a static variable in this context.